# Dijkstra algorithm part of it not making sense

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, dijkstra

This is an odd query but I don't need help at all with code, this actually works already and is great. I am simply trying to understand what's going on and I get most of it but one part is stumping me right now.

Full Algorithim

```
public class DijkstraAlgorithm 
{

    public static Stack<GameObject> Dijkstra(GameObject[] Graph, GameObject source, GameObject target)
    {

        Dictionary<GameObject, float> dist = new Dictionary<GameObject, float>();
        Dictionary<GameObject, GameObject> previous = new Dictionary<GameObject, GameObject>(); //previous NODE to the node that is currently on this script
        List<GameObject> Q = new List<GameObject>();

        foreach(GameObject v in Graph)
        {
            dist[v] = Mathf.Infinity;
            //for all gameobjects (nodes) it will insert it into our dictionary as a key (kind of like a vector in c++)
            previous[v] = null;
            Q.Add (v);

        }

        dist[source] = 0;


        //up until this point we have done what?

        // Grabbed all the nodes via Graph (Graph = all the GameObjects with tag "Node")
        // Grabbed the source which is the closest node to whatever GameObject you're on
        // Grabbed the players closest node via target
        //
        //initializing dist[v] (dist is a dictionary holding a GameObject and a float, we are 
        //accessing the GameObject key of it.) to be positive infinity
        //initializing previous 'key' = GameObject v to null
        //Adding each GameObject v to Q which is a List of GameObjects
        while(Q.Count > 0)
        {
            float shortestDistance = Mathf.Infinity; //init
            GameObject shortestDistanceNode = null; //init
            foreach(GameObject obj in Q)
            {
                if(dist[obj] < shortestDistance) //very complicated if statement that basically finds the shortest distance based on whichever gameobject distance is not infinity.
                {
                    shortestDistance = dist[obj];
                    shortestDistanceNode = obj;
                }
            }

            GameObject u = shortestDistanceNode;
            Q.Remove (u);
            //
            //Up Until Here We Have Done:
            //init shortest distance to positive infinity
            // init shortestdistancenode to null for now
            //looping through list of nodes
            //if the gameobject key's value in the dist dictionary is smaller

            //Check to see if we made it to target
            if(u == target)
            {
                Stack<GameObject> S = new Stack<GameObject>();
                while(previous[u] != null)
                {
                    S.Push (u);
                    u = previous[u];
                }
                return S;
            }

            if(dist[u] == Mathf.Infinity)
            {
                break;
            }

            foreach(GameObject v in u.GetComponent<Node>().neighbors)
            {
                float alt = dist[u] + (u.transform.position - v.transform.position).magnitude;

                if (alt < dist[v])
                {
                    dist[v] = alt;
                    previous[v] = u;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

The part I am confused about is this line right here

```
if(dist[obj] < shortestDistance) //very complicated if statement that basically finds the shortest distance based on whichever gameobject distance is not infinity.
```

So the GameObject key that it's refering to was set to Mathf.Infinity here

```
dist[v] = Mathf.Infinity;
```

Ans I don't see anywhere else we are changing that so this is where I am confused. How can the GameObject key's float value in the dist dictionary be smaller than shortestDistance which is infinity. Somewhere it has to change? I feel like there's something small I am not getting because otherwise this all makes sense. shortestDistance is positive infinity so somewhere (not seeing where) but the value for the GameObject key in the dist Dictionary must change after we are init'ing it to positive infinity.

Comment: I see it changing twice: dist[source] = 0; and in the last foreach loop: dist[v] = alt;

Comment: dist[source] would be a different gameobject though, no?

Comment: source is the object for which you are calculating the shortest path. They initialize all distances to infinity, except source. Its distance to itself is 0. Then they loop over its neighbors and calculate those distances, then the neighbors's neighbors, etc.

Comment: **Use a debugger and watch when the value changes**. Then you'll know when it changes.